# How accurate is the Linux bash time command?

Tags: linux, bash, time, sh

I want to timestamp some events in a logfile from a bash script. I need this timestamp to be as accurate as possible. I see that the standard way of doing this from bash seems to be the `time` command, which can produce a nanoseconds timestamp with the `+%s%N` option.

However, when doing this from C I remembered that multiple timekeeping functions had multiple clock sources, and not all of them were equally accurate or had the same guarantees (e.g. being monotonic). How do I know what clock source `time` uses?

Comment: Did you read the man page?

Comment: yes, I did. It says a lot about the usage, not much about the inner workings.

Comment: No? Like literally `the sum of the tms_utime and tms_cutime values in a struct tms as returned by
       times(2)`?

Comment: What `man` is that? I read it on https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html and it doesn't have that line!

Comment: But [man 1 time](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) has! [Sections in manpages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections) are important

Comment: Oh, I was looking at the wrong page all along... as a backup question: what is the difference in usage between `time(1)` and `times(2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [man 1 time](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) is rather clear:

> These statistics consist of (i) the elapsed  real  time  between
> invocation and termination, (ii) the user CPU time (the sum of the tms_utime and tms_cutime values in a struct tms as returned by
> times(2)), and (iii) the system CPU time (the sum of the tms_stime  and  tms_cstime  values  in  a  struct  tms  as  returned  by
> times(2)).

So we can go to [man 3p times](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/times.3p.html) where is just states `The accuracy of the times reported is intentionally left unspecified to allow implementations flexibility in design, from uniprocessor to multi-processor networks.` So we can go to [man 2 times](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html), and learn that it's all measured with `clock_t` and maybe we should use `clock_gettime` instead

> How do I know what clock source time uses?

As usually on a GNU system, all programs are open source. So you go and download sources of the kernel and you shell and inspect them to see how it works. I see in [bash time_command()](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/execute_cmd.c#L1326) there are many methods available and nowadays bash uses [rusage](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Resource-Usage.html) as a replacement for `times`.

> How accurate is the Linux bash time command?

Both `getrusage()` and `times()` are [system calls by themselfs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), so the values are returned straight from the kernel. My guess would be that they are measured with the accuracy the kernel can give us - so with jiffies/`HZ`.

The *resolution* of the measurement will be equal to jiffies, so usually with 300 HZ thats 3.333ms if my math is right. The *accuracy* will depend on your hardware, maybe also workload - my overestimated guess would be that the values will be right up to one or two jiffies of accuracy, so up to ~7 milliseconds.