# What explains the inaccuracy of `time` on macOS?

Tags: shell

**Note**: I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/64315882/21728 and understand that `time` is not necessarily that precise. However, I'm seeing a 4× difference between the reported `time` and time it actually took, and I'd like to understand what's causing it on macOS – that's the point of this question.

---

I'm trying to compare two ways to run a binary and they report very similar `time` info:

```
$ time ../../../node_modules/.bin/quicktype --version
quicktype version 15.0.214
Visit quicktype.io for more info.
../../../node_modules/.bin/quicktype --version  0.46s user 0.06s system 110% cpu 0.474 total

$ time $(yarn bin quicktype) --version
quicktype version 15.0.214
Visit quicktype.io for more info.
$(yarn bin quicktype) --version  0.44s user 0.06s system 110% cpu 0.449 total
```

However, the latter *feels* much slower. So I've added timestamps before and after:

```
$ date +"%T.%3N" && time $(yarn bin quicktype) --version && date +"%T.%3N"
15:11:09.667
quicktype version 15.0.214
Visit quicktype.io for more info.
$(yarn bin quicktype) --version  0.49s user 0.06s system 108% cpu 0.513 total
15:11:11.400
```

Indeed, the difference between `15:11:09.667` and `15:11:11.400` is almost **two seconds** but `time` is reporting about **0.5 second**. What explains this rather vast difference?

Comment: Just as a test, since I'm not sure how MacOS's `time` command works, what does `time echo $(sleep 3)` say?  That would help distinguish whether the time spent to expand the `$(...)` is included.  Have you also checked the man page for `time(1)` and/or your shell to see if the `total` number is meant to be CPU time or real time?

Comment: @NateEldredge Interestingly, `time echo $(sleep 3)` doesn't output anything at all (just one additional empty line): https://i.stack.imgur.com/FunIR.png. I'm in a Zsh shell if that matters (`time` is `/usr/bin/time` on my machine – `man time` says it's a BSD utility, as expected on macOS).

Comment: If you want to be sure command substitutions are included, encapsulate the whole thing in a function and time that function.

Comment: As it is, you're not necessarily counting the time `yarn` takes, but may only be seeing the time used by `quicktype`.

Comment: Alternately, how about using `yarn` to update your PATH so you only need to call it once, instead of once per program you want to run from a location it provides?

Comment: So if you're sure that `time` is `/usr/bin/time` and not a shell builtin, then the time to run `yarn` is definitely not included.  Would that account for the discrepancy?

Comment: @NateEldredge The real-world difference is certainly due to involving `yarn`. I didn't realize that `time` only accounts for the internal binary (how would it even parse it?).

Comment: BTW, after some more poking around `time` is different than `/usr/bin/time` on my machine. The first is probably some (Zsh?) built-in while `/usr/bin/time` is BSD time.

Comment: With an external command like `/usr/bin/time`, the shell expands the `$(...)` command substitution by running `yarn` before `/usr/bin/time` is even started.  So all that `/usr/bin/time` sees is its arguments `/usr/bin/time .../quicktype --version` and that is all it times; it has no way of even knowing how those arguments were produced.  With a shell builtin there is at least the possibility for `yarn` to be included, but it appears that in zsh it is not.  `time /bin/true $(sleep 3)` under zsh prints a time near zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @NateEldredge, makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

I was using the `time` wrong.

First, `time` is different from `/usr/bin/time` on my Mac:

- `time` is a shell built-in (I use Zsh)
- `/usr/bin/time` is BSD time

This gives the expected results:

```
$ /usr/bin/time bash -c '../../../node_modules/.bin/quicktype --version'
quicktype version 15.0.214
Visit quicktype.io for more info.
        0.49 real         0.47 user         0.06 sys

$ /usr/bin/time bash -c '$(yarn bin quicktype) --version'
quicktype version 15.0.214
Visit quicktype.io for more info.
        2.02 real         1.92 user         0.27 sys
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, for an external command `cmd`, it is the case that shell expansions are done by the shell before `cmd` is started.  This includes command substitution `cmd $(other_cmd)`, globbing `cmd *.txt`, variable expansion `cmd $FOO`, and so forth.   So `cmd` is executed with the result of the expansion as its arguments, and never sees the original command line typed by the user.

Thus if `time` were an ordinary external command, as it is if you use `/usr/bin/time`, then the command `yarn bin quicktype` would be run before `time` even starts, and it would be just as if you had run `time .../quicktype --version`.  It only measures the time taken to execute `.../quicktype --version`, and it would not (and could not) account for the time taken for the shell to generate that command line by running `yarn`.

Now the situation here is not quite that simple because `time` is actually a builtin command in many shells, and not an external command.  So it doesn't necessarily have to follow the above behavior.  However, in my tests, `zsh`'s builtin `time` behaves the same, and does not count the time taken to run the substituted command `yarn`.  On the other hand, in `bash`, the `time` builtin does include it.

As you saw, you can circumvent the issue by timing the running of a new shell which does both the command substitution (running `yarn`) and the resulting `../quicktype` command itself.  Then you will definitely include the time taken by both steps.